# How to sign both release and debug builds for a single flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If i configure the flavor, only release build is signed.
If i configure the build types that affects all flavors.

I need to have a debug build that is signed with a particular key that is used only in quality environment. Any way to configure this on gradle?

Update:
Bellow my attempt following Xav's as suggestion. Maybe i got something wrong.

```
signingConfigs {
qua {
  ...
}
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if(variant.name == "flavorQuaDebug") {
        variant.mergedFlavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.qua
    }
}
```

The result:

---

> Variant: flavorQuaDebug
>
> Config: debug Store:
>
> /Users/..../.android/debug.keystore
>
> Alias: AndroidDebugKey
>
> ...

Comment: So, are you asking how to stipulate a signing key for the `debugQuality` build variant?

Comment: yes, i am asking how to sign the DebugQuality build variant, or both Quality variants

Comment: A product flavor has a `signingConfig` property (see [the DSL docs](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:signingConfig)), so if you're willing to use the same signing key for both `debugQuality` and `releaseQuality`, then Eugene's answer should work.

Comment: But it doesn't. I run signingReport report and i see the debug build gets the signature from the default debug store, not the one i specify. I told in the question.

Comment: Hmmm... OK. Check out [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68135601) and see if [Xav's comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68135601#comment5) works. Make sure that you are on the current Android Plugin for Gradle (3.0.0).

Comment: I am using Gradle plugin 3.0.0. The suggestion looks good but i could put it to work. i will post my attempt, at least will help to avoid assumptions in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing a signingConfigs for the release and the special product flavor, and add that to your product flavor config:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".keystore")
      storePassword "${storePassword}"
      keyAlias "${keyAlias}"
      keyPassword "${keyPassword}"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }

  productFlavors {
    (your_product_flavor) {
        applicationId "com.example.product"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Why that should work? specifying at the flavour level will only affect release version.

Comment: My case too: It does not sign the debug variant of the flavour...